# android existing project taking too long to open

Tags: android

Recently i have formatted my windows so i have to reinstall android studio ( little background previously my sdk was in E drive and after formatting it is now is D drive) now i wish to open previous projects in android but whenever i click open existing project it is not opening 
here is the screenshot 
[image: i dont know what to do now]

a little help would be appreciated

Comment: Screenshots says `E:\ashish\MMM`. Suggest placing the current version in a temp folder and then importing it as a new project.

Comment: yeah i thought if its not opening from home page maybe i should first try creating a new project then open it from file menu but still same result

Comment: Key word was _importing_ not _open_.

Comment: so now what should i do ?

Comment: did you set jdk global variable? as environment variable?

Comment: wow really ? -_- if i have gotten solution from there i wouldnt be here

Answer (score 1):

All of the following is assuming you did a fresh install of Android Studio and the SDK.

If you did not do a fresh install, this may be causing some issues. For your sanity - do a fresh install (I know it is a lot to download).

Move all of your old projects to a different directory (lets call it `Old_Workspace`). Make a backup too, just in case.

Start Android Studio.

On the Android Studio "Launch" window there are a number of options. On Linux, with Android Studio Version 2.2 Beta, one of the options is *Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)*. This is the option you want.

Browse to the `Old_Workspace` and find the base directory for the project you want to work on and hit the *OK* option.

Android Studio will run a few test and try to fix everything up for you. This may take a few moments.

Save the project. The next time you open the project, use the normal way. Your project should also be on the left hand side of the Android Studio Launch window.

Answer (score 0):

It is only because the existing project might have built with the old version of the android studio, don't worry android studio will take some time to make that old project become compatible with yours, and it will open within the short time later. Best of luck!